# Google Data Studio Community Connector: Accessing URL Parameters in App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, anvil

I am following the [Row level filtering with Embedded dashboards](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials) tutorial to build a secure, multi-tenant dashboard using Data Studio as the reporting UI/backend (and [Anvil](https://anvil.works/) as the front-end in Python), with the aim of filtering data from a BigQuery table based on specific user permisisons.

I have completed the [initial connector tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors#0) successfully as recommended.  So far I have also completed the following steps (1-4) successfully :

1. Build user authentication in Anvil and set permissions in `user` table (JSON containing specific field values each user is permitted to view)
2. Build mechanism to create `access_token` in Anvil, based on hex md5 hash of a combination of user and unix timestamp, with one hour expiry
3. Set and store `app_secret` securely in Anvil to authenticate inbound requests
4. Create API endpoint in Anvil which validates the `app_secret` and validates `access_token` and returns JSON containing `user_email` and `permitted_accounts`

Now I've got to the point of building the custom connector, with the aim of building the next part of the flow:

5. Pass `access_token` to Data Studio by encoding and including it in the embed URL (the report will be embedded via an iFrame)  as per [this](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials#embed_the_dashboard_in_your_platform) section
6. Extract `access_token` from embed URL in App Script as per the statement "This will be used to capture a token from embed URL's parameters." from [this](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials#write_the_connector_code) section
7. Hit the API endpoint with the `app_secret` and `access_token` from App Script to validate and receive the user permissions associated with the `access_token` IF validation checks pass in Anvil, otherwise return appropriate error message
8. Construct query based on user permissions and get data from BigQuery using this [approach](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery)
   ... then set schema etc...

However, upon reaching step 6 in this flow where I need to parse the `access_token` from the URL, the code included in the [Write the Connector Code](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials#write_the_connector_code) section takes the `token` as a user-inputted text field and does not take it from the embed URL's parameters (which to me makes no sense as making a user continually manually transpose a short-lived token seems to negate the point of this exercise).

I am also unable to find documentation in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference) on how to achieve this.

PLEASE, does anybody know how to capture parameters from Report Embed URLs in an App Script Community Connector?  I assumed it was possible from the documentation:

> getConfig() should return at least one config item. This will be used to capture a token from embed URL's parameters.

Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: In the config is the token parameter `.setAllowOverride(true);` and in the report settings the enabled filter by url is activated? Create a dummy inputbox in your report and see it in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. I'm assuming `access_token` is an overridable config parameter in your `getConfig`.

b. When you create the initial report, during the data source creation, you can put in any value in `access_token` config field. However, check the box to 'Allow "access_token" to be modified in reports'. That means, report viewers will be able to override this value even though they do not have edit access to the report or the data source.

c. Confirm that your setp #5 is following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters#set_url_parameters) to pass the override value for `access_token`.

d. That's it. Now it is irrelevant what value you put in for `access_token` during initial report creation. For user X, your portal was pass the value `hash(user, timestamp)` as the value for `access_token`. In your connector's `getData` function, `request.configParams.access_token` will return that specific value. You can then call your endpoint with that value to get back the user identity.

Comment: Thanks @MinhazKazi, I have finally managed to get this part to work thanks to your detailed explanation!  However, I am attempting to get data from BigQuery and I am encountering the "The number of columns received in the data returned from the community connector does not match the number of columns ..." error.  I have been using this connector as a template and when debugging I can see that the response to the getData(request) does not match the expected format (i.e. schema and row data for the specific field subset), and as such am stumped...

Comment: Sorry, this is the template: https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/0192a29517ac89238519e2affe8a881afb99d52d/world-bank/src

Comment: Are you using advanced services/useQueryConfig in your getData?

Comment: I am now, thanks @MinhazKazi!  Works a treat...